# How to split video into parts audio/video/text in one command?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have one video file `.mkv`.
Inside this file, there is a video track, 3 audio tracks, 2 subtitles, a poster file, and a backdrop file.
Does ffmpeg know how to split `.mkv` into separate parts, video / 3 audio / 2 subtitles?

```
~# ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mkv
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Duration: 01:37:03.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3605 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:33:51.582
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1024x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
    Stream #0:1(rus): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : MVO «West Video»
    Stream #0:2(spa): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : MVO Spain-1
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : MVO TRK
    Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: subrip (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : RUS
    Stream #0:5(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : Eng
    Stream #0:6(und): Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 780x1170 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:3], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      filename        : poster.jpg
      mimetype        : image/jpeg
      title           : poster
      LANGUAGE        : und
    Stream #0:7(und): Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x719 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1280:719], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      filename        : backdrop.jpg
      mimetype        : image/jpeg
      title           : backdrop
      LANGUAGE        : und
```

**I need:**

- Video

  - input0.mp4
- Audio

  - input0.m4a
  - input1.m4a
  - input2.m4a
- Subtitle

  - input0.vtt
  - input1.vtt

These commands do the splitting, but I need to know exactly how many audio files and how many subtitle files are in the `mkv`.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mkv \
  -map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 output0.mp4
```

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mkv \
  -map 0:a:0 -c:a aac output0.m4a \
  -map 0:a:1 -c:a aac output1.m4a \
  -map 0:a:2 -c:a aac output2.m4a
```

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mkv \
  -map 0:s:0 output0.vtt \
  -map 0:s:1 output1.vtt
```

Is it possible to make such divisions without knowing the file number `0:a:2`, `0:s:1`?

Comment: There is no such automatic, built-in feature. But see [ffprobe count video and audio streams / tracks](https://superuser.com/q/1381642/) which could be helpful.